# Inserting elements into an array

Tags: excel, vba

I have an multidimensional array in Excel:

[image: array in excel sheet]

In the VBA script I have the following code:

```
Dim actualWeights
actualWeights = Range("A7:E21").Value
```

After some calculations, I want to add the missing ID's in place in the array. So in this case ID 3, 4, 6 etc. To my regret there is no append or insert function available. What is the best way to do this?

Added:
So after some calculations I want to insert in place:

```
<id: 3, weight: 34,92, measured: false, dailyLoss: 0,31, prediction: 0,00>
```

And then I want to insert in place:

```
<id: 4, weight: 34,60, measured: false, dailyLoss: 0,31, prediction: 0,00>
```

Etc. Until all the missing id's are filled. Id's should be 1 up to 24 in this example.

Comment: All at once, or each of them at a time? How the code would know which row to be inserted (in both cases)? Should the array to be iterated and in case of not consecutive ID, to ask the user about the missing one? If yes, where from the necessary values for the other columns to be found? Do you need only an example of insertion, or a piece of code to do something according to your need?

Comment: For each ID I have to do some calculation... so the inserting Is in a For loop. There is no interaction with the user... the missing ID's are calculated and added.

Comment: It is, but based on what? You can see the place using your eyes, but how the code should understand where to insert a row? And which content for the rest of the columns to be inserted...

Comment: Why insertion and not adding to the range end and filtering it after that?

Comment: Is the ID unique? I guess so but you did not mention! What will the ID be for weigth `31,49`?

Comment: And it also seems weight is unique as well?

Comment: Where does the calculation get the parameters of the added items?  It's trivial to find an unused ID, but how do you calculate the associated weight and other parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the data in VBA exactly the same way you would do it in the worksheet without VBA.

Manually, you would add missing records starting at row #22 and sort the table by *ID.  (this will shift the new records up into their desired positions)*

Using VBA, bring the data in with something like:

```
actualWeights = Range("A7:E100").Value
```

Then insert the missing data and finally use VBA to sort the final product.

Comment: My guess is that it seems the OP wants to add only unique IDs. So, one needs to check for the ID beforehand. And it also seems that OP wants to fill gaps. And what will happen in case the weight is `31,49`. No ID left? Does the OP want to shift the IDs?  For me the post leaves a lot of questions open.

Comment: @Storax  I agree with all your points.  The devil is always in the details.  My point is that it is easier to append at the bottom and then to sort than it is to several re-dims to insert in place.

Comment: Yes, adding the data at the end and then sorting is certainly quicker and easier. It just depends on the requirements the OP has.

Answer (score 1):

**Insertion of array rows**

Just for fun and to demonstrate insertion of a new items row into an existing array using the `Application.Index()` function:

**Example call close to OP**

```
Sub myData()
' Site: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60588030/inserting-elements-into-an-array
    '[0] get original data
    Dim actualWeights
    actualWeights = MySheet.Range("A7:E21").Value             ' << change to actual sheet's CodeName

    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    '[1] define data to be inserted
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Dim tobeInserted

    '<id: 3, weight: 34,92, measured: false, dailyLoss: 0,31, prediction: 0,00>
    tobeInserted = Array(3, 34.92, False, 0.31, 0)
    ins actualWeights, tobeInserted

    '<id: 4, weight: 34,60, measured: false, dailyLoss: 0,31, prediction: 0,00>
    tobeInserted = Array(4, 34.6, False, 0.31, 0)
    ins actualWeights, tobeInserted

    '[2] optional display at any range offset
    MySheet.Range("A7").Resize(UBound(actualWeights), 5).Offset(0, 6).Value = actualWeights

End Sub
```

**Procedure call `ins()`**

```
Sub ins(arr, newItems)
'Note: newItems e.g. <id: 3, weight: 34,92, measured: false, dailyLoss: 0,31, prediction: 0,00>
    '[1] Get (unique) id
    Dim id As Long: id = newItems(0)

    '[2] Get row numbers including the one to be inserted, e.g. Array(1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15)
    Dim i As Long, ii As Long
    ReDim tmp(1 To 1, 1 To 1000)
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i, 1) < id Then ii = ii + 1: tmp(1, ii) = ii
        If arr(i, 1) > id Then ii = ii + 1: tmp(1, ii) = ii: Exit For
    Next i
    For i = ii + 1 To UBound(arr) + 1: tmp(1, i) = i - 1: Next ' << Edited: added missing Next statement /2020-03-12
    ReDim Preserve tmp(1 To 1, 1 To i - 1)
    tmp = Application.Transpose(tmp)

    '[3] restructure by inserting new row
    arr = Application.Index(arr, tmp, Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))

    '[4] Insert new items
    Dim curr As Long
    If id > arr(ii, 1) Then ii = UBound(tmp)
    For curr = 0 To UBound(newItems)
        arr(ii, curr + 1) = newItems(curr)
    Next curr
End Sub
```